# "start a program on connection" for a specific user in WS 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I am trying to execute a program when a specific user logs on, but it does not work.

What I did is:

Computer Management / Local Users And Groups / User

then edit the desired user, click Environment sheet.

In this sheet, I check on "start a program on connection" and then I specific the path.

When the user logs on, the application is not launched and he has access to the desktop.

I installed Remote Desktop Services with the Gateway. Could it affect?

Thank you

Comment: Are you logging on via RDS?